# How to create combo box in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Hi anybody can tell me how to create combo box in iphone (like same as Spinner in Android). Here i developing a simple application, i need to load some value to combo box. But not using UIPicker. Can anybody help me pls.

Comment: UIPicker is the standard control that is the equivalent to a combo box.  It's familiar and standard to iPhone users - why would you want to use something different?

Comment: i cant to reduce the height of the UIPicker ? can u tel me how to reduce the height of UIPicker

Answer (score 1):

you can set your pickerview frame like follow

```
[pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 120)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this Code..

https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

it is the best solution for combo box.